# Remove numbers from string that are not next to letters

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I strip numbers that are not next to letters in a string, for example

> "13 Some Street, Some Place, PE15 0TZ"

In this case I want to remove the 13 only, not the numbers in the post code.

> "M1, Some Place, PE15 0TZ"

In the above case it would not remove anything as all numbers are next to letters.

I have found lots of code that can strip numbers from strings (`.replace(/\d+/g, '')`) but none that take its neighbours into account

Comment: **Non-regex** - `input.split(/\s+/g).filter( s => isNaN(s) ).join(" ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a word boundary `\b` on both sides and match one or more digits `\d+` to select only 13:

[`\b\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/XBKnEC/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "13 Some Street, Some Place, PE15 0TZ",
  "M1, Some Place, PE15 0TZ",
  "Some Street, Some Place, 15 PE15 0TZ 16",
];
let pattern = /\b\d+\b/g;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.replace(pattern, ""));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex to test if a number is surrounded by spaces or the beginning/end of the string:

```
/(^|\s)\d+(\s|$)/g
```

```js
examples = ["13 Some Street, Some Place, PE15 0TZ", "M1, Some Place, PE15 0TZ"]
for (var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++)
{
    console.log(
        examples[i].replace(/(^|\s)\d+(\s|$)/g, '$1$2')
    );
}
```